# Specify format for autogenerated Firestore document Ids

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a small game where people are able to join a room using a six-digit pin. Every room is represented by a document in a Firestore collection, where the room pin is the id of a room document.

My initial idea was to randomly generate a six-digit pin and check if a document with that id exists. If it does, create a new document with the generated pin, if not, generate a new pin and check if that id is free. This method will work, however, with a bit of bad luck it might cause a lot of unnecessary requests to the database.

My question is, therefore: is it possible to specify a format of the autogenerated id's? Or, if it is not possible, is there a way to fetch all documents id's to locally check whether or not the id exists?

Comment: The chances of duplicate IDs is high as mentioned by @Frank especially with just 6 digits. I'd recommend considering increasing the length of the PINs or stick with Firestore IDs. [uuid-int](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-int) is another option if you need unique IDs with numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a format for the auto-generated IDs but you can check if a room with same ID exists. If yes, then try new ID else create a room with same ID.

```
async function addRoom(roomId) {
    const roomRef = admin.firestore().collection("rooms").doc(roomId)
    if ((await roomRef.get()).exists) {
        return addRoom(generatePin())
    } else {
        await roomRef.set({ ... })
    }
    return `${roomId} created`
}

function generatePin() {
    return String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 100000)
}

return addRoom(generatePin())
    .then(() => console.log("Room created"))
    .catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

PS: This might end up in some recursive state so I'd recommend using Firestore's IDs or [uuid-int](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-int) is you need numerical IDs only.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now, and it works fine. My worry is that it can take a lot of tries until I find a valid room pin, which will exhaust my read quota very quickly. Do you think a valid strategy might be to get all the existing room pins and find a valid one locally?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to specify the format of automatic IDs generated by the Firestore SDKs. They are purely random, and have an amount of entropy that statistically guarantees there won't be collisions (the chance where two clients generate the same ID is infinitesimally small), and minimizes the chance of hotspots (created when writing lots of documents or index values to the same area on a disk).

You can generate whatever auto-ID format you want however. You'll just have to accept a higher chance of collisions, as you already did, and the fact that you may experience hotspots when the documents are in the same area on a disk.